# Unexpected behavior of HTML::Entities

Tags: perl, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

I'm a newbie user of Perl's HTML::Entities routine `decode_entities()` to
convert headlines scraped from news media websites.

Here's a good result:

Before: `Texas grand jury clears Planned Parenthood, indicts its&nbsp;accusers`
After: `Texas grand jury clears Planned Parenthood, indicts its accusers`

But here's a puzzling result:

Before: `Big changes could be coming to Utah&#8217;s criminal justice&nbsp;system`
After: `Big changes could be coming to Utahâs criminal justiceÂ system`

Notice that not only was the `&#8217;` code not converted to a single quote, the `&nbsp;` wasn't decoded into a space, unlike in the first example.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between your first and second example is that the first one does not contain any code points above 255, while the second one does. So, the first string can be displayed according to the native 8-bit character set of your system (most likely ISO 8859-1/Latin 1), but the second cannot. The reason for this, according to [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html), is that "using a code point above 255 implies Unicode for the whole string".

Since you now have Unicode characters in your string, you'll need to properly encode your text for output, otherwise you'll see "strange characters" (just like the ones in your example!). Since you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'm not sure what your output method is, but let's just assume `STDOUT` to make things easy. There are a couple different ways to encode your text into an octet stream:

1. Manually, using the [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) module
2. Automatically, using the correct I/O layer

I prefer the second option because it's less tedious. To do that, we'll just call [`binmode()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) on `STDOUT`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Entities;

my $str = 'Big changes could be coming to Utah&#8217;s criminal justice&nbsp;system';
my $decoded = decode_entities($str);

binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
printf("%s\n%vx\n", $decoded, $decoded);
```

Output:

```
$ perl foo.pl
Big changes could be coming to Utah’s criminal justice system
42.69.67.20.63.68.61.6e.67.65.73.20.63.6f.75.6c.64.20.62.65.20.63.6f.6d.69.6e.67.20.74.6f.20.55.74.61.68.2019.73.20.63.72.69.6d.69.6e.61.6c.20.6a.75.73.74.69.63.65.a0.73.79.73.74.65.6d
```

You can see that there's code point `2019` ([right single quotation mark](http://www.codetable.net/hex/2019)) between characters `68` and `73` (*h* and *s*, respectively), and also an `a0` ([non-breaking space](http://www.codetable.net/hex/a0)) between `65` and `73`, which would be *e* and *s*.

In addition to the aforementioned [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) reference, you should also read [perluniintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html), [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) (short!), and [perlunifaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html) if you're interested in learning more about how Perl handles Unicode and character encoding in general.